# How to go into each sub directory and list the files and give the name of the directory to the output

Tags: linux, bash

I have several sub-directories within a main directory. I want to go into each sub-directory and list the text files and give the name of the sub-directory to the output.

```
for d in /home/*/;do
cd $d
ls *.txt > dir_*_all_txt.list
done
```

I want to replace the `dir_*` with the name of the sub-directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manipulate strings (see `Parameter Expansion`, or just search for the string `##`, in the `bash` manpage) from within bash to remove everything up to and including the last slash:

```
pax> for i in $HOME/tmp* ; do echo $i ${i##*/} ; done
/home/pax/tmp tmp
/home/pax/tmp1 tmp1
/home/pax/tmp2 tmp2
/home/pax/tmp3 tmp3
/home/pax/tmp4 tmp4
/home/pax/tmp5 tmp5
```

So, in your case, that would be along the lines of:

```
for d in /home/* ;do
    cd $d
    ls *.txt > ${d##*/}_all_txt.list
done
```

Though I should mention your code won't currently differentiate between directories and files in the directory you're examining - you may want to use `find -type d` to find only directories, or check it inside the loop with a simple `if [[ -d ${d} ]]`:

```
for d in /home/* ; do
    if [[ -d "${d}" ]] ; then
        cd $d
        ls *.txt > "${d##*/}_all_txt.list"
    fi
done
```